# Why can't compress many unpack statements into one as the form of unpack("Lfffffff",$bytes)?

Tags: php, arrays, file, binaryfiles, unpack

```
<?php
//it is unnecessary to get the data file.
    $handle = fopen('data', 'rb');
    fread($handle,"64");
//it is no use to parse the first 64 bytes here.
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("L",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
    $bytes= fread($handle,"4");
    print_r(unpack("f",$bytes));
    echo  "<br/>";
?>
```

I got the right output with the code.

```
Array ( [1] => 20150416 )
Array ( [1] => 1.0499999523163 )
Array ( [1] => 1.25 )
Array ( [1] => 1.0299999713898 )
Array ( [1] => 1.1900000572205 )
Array ( [1] => 509427008 )
Array ( [1] => 566125248 )
Array ( [1] => 509427008 )
```

Now I want to compress many unpack statements into one as the form of  `unpack("Lfffffff",$bytes)` with the following code.

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('data', 'rb');
    fread($handle,"64");
    //it is no use to parse the first 64 bytes here.
    $bytes= fread($handle,"32");
    print_r(unpack("Lfffffff",$bytes));
?>
```

Why I get the only one output,no other parsed data in my result? How to fix it?

```
Array ( [fffffff] => 20150416 )
```

The data file was opened with notepad++ and check by the plugin--TextFX .
Only 96 bytes parsed here,the first 64 bytes omitted by fread.

[image]

Comment: can you post your file content?

Comment: it is a binary file ,please tell me how can i paste it here ?

Comment: i have paste the data file in external link,the administrater  make the post hold on status ,now i repost it here and delete the data file in  external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [unpack doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php):

> The unpacked data is stored in an associative array. To accomplish
>   this you have to name the different format codes and separate them by
>   a slash /. If a repeater argument is present, then each of the array
>   keys will have a sequence number behind the given name.

Try this example:

```
<?php

$array = array (20150416, 1.0499999523163, 1.25, 1.0299999713898, 1.1900000572205, 509427008, 566125248, 509427008);

$output = pack('L', $array[0]);

for($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $output .= pack('f', $array[$i]);
}   

print_r(unpack("LL/f7", $output));

?>
```

In `unpack("LL/f7", $output)` the first `L` refers to *unsigned long* the second `L` to the index in the array (see the first element in the output) the `/` (read the first part of the answer) and `f` refers to *float* and the `7` to seven float values.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [L] => 20150416
    [1] => 1.0499999523163
    [2] => 1.25
    [3] => 1.0299999713898
    [4] => 1.1900000572205
    [5] => 509427008
    [6] => 566125248
    [7] => 509427008
)
```

In your case should be:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('data', 'rb');
    $bytes= fread($handle,"32");
    print_r(unpack("LL/f7",$bytes));
?>
```

Comment: @it_is_a_literature do you test my example?

Comment: i tested it ,it is ok, i am serching material on the format. In the "LL/f7" ,the number 7 means  f will be 7 times ,two problems remain.

Comment: "LL/f7"  ,the `LL` first L is unsigned long, what the second `L `mean here?

Comment: what does the `/` in "LL/f7" mean here?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature the first L refer to *unsigned long* the second to the index in the array (see the first element) the / (read the first part of the answer) and f refers to *float* and the 7 to seven float values